# Z3 compact lollipop update close all apps icon missing

Tags: sony-xperia-z3

When I now press to see apps running, I can no longer close all? 
I have to swipe individually to remove. Z3 compact.
How can I close all apps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They removed it because even on stock android lollipop there isn't and also because there is something about the apps only activating when you go into them so there wasn't a need to put the button in